# Excel vba incluse headers in the result when retriving excel data with ado using where in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I know that I must set HDR=NO so the headers to be included in the results. But when I set it I cannot use the where in the SQL statement. Any ideas how to fix it;

```
Sub adoExcel()

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objrecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'*************************************************************************************
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\Users\sp\Desktop\test ado excel\test.xls;" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"
'*************************************************************************************
'where Number =2
objrecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$] where Number =1", _
objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset objrecordset

'*************************************************************************************
' Loop through the recordset and send data to the Immediate Window
'**************************************************************************************
'objrecordset.MoveFirst

'Do
   ' Debug.Print objrecordset![Name] & " " & objrecordset![Number]
   ' objrecordset.MoveNext
'Loop Until objrecordset.EOF

'**************************************************************************************
'ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset objrecordset![Name] & " " & objrecordset![Number]
'*************************************
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good question highlighting the use of HDR=NO property of Excel's connection string. Glad you included the code as well. Also, I noticed you have asked 3 questions but not marked any question as answered. Is there a reason for not marking any question as answered?

Comment: Regardless of the `HDR` setting you could still access the field names via the `Fields` collection of the `Recordset` object

Answer (score 0):

When you use HDR=NO, your fields are implicitly referred using F1, F2 etc. So, if your data looked like this:

```
  A      B
1 Name   Number
2 John   100
3 Matt   200
```

Your previous query:

```
Select ... from [Sheet1$] where Number = "200"
```

will look like

```
Select ... from [Sheet1$] where [F2] = "200"
```

Your code will look like this:

```
Sub adoExcel()

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objrecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\sp\Desktop\test ado excel\test.xls;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"

    ' Notice that I have placed 200 in quotations assuming Text information
    ' Import Export Mode (IMEX) is set to mixed-type (value of 1)
    ' Also, field name used in WHERE clause is F2
    objrecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$] where [F2]= ""200""", objConnection

    objrecordset.MoveFirst
    Do
        ' Notice the use of Fields F1 and F2
        Debug.Print objrecordset![F1] & " " & objrecordset![F2]
        objrecordset.MoveNext
    Loop Until objrecordset.EOF

End Sub
```

References: [Implicit field name when HDR=0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819), and [IMEX properties](http://www.instantpages.ltd.uk/ADODB_WP.htm)